# synchronize an MS Access table to an online spreadsheet

Tags: ms-access-2007

is there cheap, quick and easy method to synchronizing an MS Access table to an online spreadsheet?  I do not know web programming  nor do I know VBA and I am on a very tight budget

my objective is to post a spreadsheet online and the the user would enter their comments into a specific cell and it would be autosaved.
thanks very much in advance, Nathaniel, 
 Office 2007, XP

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is to try out Google Docs (http://docs.google.com). It's similar to MS Office, but everything is in "the cloud" and many users can collaborate realtime (i.e. seeing each others updates instantly). It might be that the spreadsheet might be what you need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: google docs woudl be ideal , except it doesnt seem to link to external data sources. PLease advise

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task.  It can be done but you'd have to know web programming at least.  Your best bet is to make the spreadsheet shared and allow users to edit it that way.  I believe that's under "Tools".

Comment: I think it would all depend on whether or not there's a website with a web service in place that Access could communicate. It would seem to me that Office Live would be ideally suited to something like this, but I don't know if MS has implemented that functionality or not.